# i.MX6Q Core3's IRQ can not be triggered

Tags: interrupt, cortex-a

all

I'm porting an RTOS to i.MX6Qual machine, the basic job has been done, threads can run on all 4 cores.

**But, Core3 IRQ handler will not be triggered at some time** :(

I have read the GIC manual and dump GIC interface registers, show below. and the ICCRPR & ICCHPIR value confused me, why ICCIAR=0x3FF while ICCRPR = 0 :

```
ICCICR = 1
ICCPMR = F8
ICCBPR = 2
ICCIAR = 3FF            // ack
ICCEOIR = 0
ICCRPR = 0              // running priority
ICCHPIR = 0             // highest priority pending
ICCABPR = 3
ICCIIDR = 3901243B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ack SGI through EOI with the unmatched Core ID will cause this problem**

[Cortex-A9 SMP GICC_RPR always be 0, interrupt not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447836/cortex-a9-smp-gicc-rpr-always-be-0-interrupt-not-triggered)