# Cortex-A9 SMP GICC_RPR always be 0, interrupt not triggered

Tags: arm, cortex-a

#### Context

on i.MX6Quad board, when the system running, I found that Core3 can not deal with any interrupt.

view the GIC interface registers by Trace32, the GICC_RPR is always 0, which means the highest priority event is running, so it explain the uppon question: lower priority event cannot be processed.

#### Question

I have insert a instruction : write 0 to GICC_EOI , which can change GICC_RPR to idle priority(0xFF), but it doesn't work, keep 0.

#### Goal

I want to do priority drop and deactivate success.

#### References

- *gic arch specf* : 3.2.1 Priority drop and interrupt deactivation

> Priority drop is the drop in the Running priority that occurs on a valid write > to an EOIR, either the
> GICC_EOIR or the GICC_AEOIR.
>
> On priority drop, the running priority is reduced from the priority of the
> interrupt referenced by the
> EOIR write to either

Comment: I found the temporary solution: avoid send SGIs by other cores except core0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing Zero to EOI does not help. When an interrupt fires, you have to read GICC_IAR register. The value you get is the interrupt number that fired. If you are in legacy mode, you have to write this interrupt number to EOI to retire this interrupt. If you are in priority drop mode, writing this number to EOI decreases the priority, writing the same value to DI will retire the interrupt (check GICC_CTLR to confirm your mode). Hope this clears up the confusion with RPR and EOI.

Some pointers to debug your issue:
1. Check the GICD_ITARGET registers to see there are interrupts pointed at CPU3.
2. Ensure the interrupts that you are expecting in CPU3 (if anything specific) is not masked in the distributor
3. Check GICC_PMR for CPU3 to see that the priority is not too high. An interrupt is forwarded from distributor to cpu interface only if its priority is higher than the value in this register
4. Check CPU interface for CPU3 is enabled
5. Check GICD_ISPEND to see if the interrupt in question is pending

NOTE: Be careful when using T32 to debug GIC. T32 works by reading values from registers/memory. This has undesired effects on some GIC registers, for eg GICC_IAR register can only read once to acknowledge the interrupt. Further reads will return spurious interrupt numbers. When T32 is connected and a window is opened to read GICC registers, this will cause an 'orphan' interrupt that no one can take care of. I would suggest putting in logs in the interrupt handling logic to debug issues.

Comment: Thank u for your method,sir, I follow the advises and check GIC's registers, found the problem that **SGI0 always keep active and cannot change to idle, as its priority is highest, core looks like die**. Here is the dumped information, I can't understand why GICC_IAR=0x3FF while EOIR=0 & GICC_RPR=0 & GICC_HPIR=0, how these status generated?

Comment: `ICCICR = 1`
`ICCPMR = F0`
`ICCBPR = 2`
`ICCIAR = 3FF`
`ICCEOIR = 0`
`ICCRPR = 0`
`ICCHPIR = 0`
`ICCABPR = 3`
`ICCIIDR = 3901243B`

`ICDDCR = 1`
`ICDICTR = FC64`
`ICDIIDR = 102043B`
`ICDISERn[0] = FFFF`
`ICDICERn[0] = FFFF`
`ICDISPRn[0] = 1`
`ICDICPRn[0] = 1`
`ICDABRn[0] = 1`
`ICDIPRn[0] = 0`
`ICDIPTRn[0] = 08080808`
`ICDICFRn[0] = AAAAAAAA`
`ICDSGIR = 0`

Comment: After an interrupt is fired GIC_IAR can only be read once to get actual interrupt number. After that reads fo GIC_IAR will return 'spurious interrupt' number; in your case 0x3FF. This is why I asked you not to use T32 for debugging GICC issues. EOIR is a write register I don't understand the point of reading its value. Can you confirm the results of the experiments mentioned in Para 2 in my answer?

Comment: Yes, the result below: **1.** ICDIPTRn[0] = 08080808H, 08H means bind on Core3 **2.** SGI0 can not be masked according to manual **3.**GICC_PMR=0xF0,the priority is lower then 0x0 **4.**ICCICR = 1, means GIC interface is enabled **5.**ICDISPRn[0] = 1, yes, SGI0 is pending, and as GICD_ISACTIVERn[0] = 1, which means SGI0 is active.

Comment: Maybe I have do something that result GIC into UNPREDICTABLE state ? for example, a write EOIR value does not match the last valid interrupt value read from IAR register.

Comment: Please confirm was T32 attached on CPU3 when these values were read? Also please confirm the EOI mode. GICD_ISACTIVER being set to 1 is good news. It means that CPU3 got the interrupt and he did an IAR. The interrupt is now acknowledged. After CPU3 has finished processing the interrupt it should write the same number to EOI and possibly to DI (if and only if priority drop eoi mode is enabled)

Comment: I just attached T32 to Core0, and EOI mode, ICDDCR = 1, which means '*GICC_EOIR has both priority drop and deactivate interrupt functionality.
Accesses to the GICC_DIR are UNPREDICTABLE*'. **interesting, while I read IAR, it change to 0x3FF, if the value written to EOI does not matched, it makes this BUG?**

Comment: based on the above speculate, insert debug-info to observe, each IAR read matches the EOIR write, and the values are equal

Comment: You are in legacy mode and don't need to worry about DI register at all. You can only read the IAR register once per interrupt, if you read it again (without the interrupt firing again) it will return spurious interrupt number ( I had already mentioned this once). You can't read this value for logging or using T32 it will mess up the logic. Value read from IAR and written to EOI should match. If not you will have a orphan/hanging interrupt. No further interrupts from that interrupt number/line will fire.

Comment: as confirmed above, in this status, IAR=3FF and RPR(running priority reg)=0, means Core3 is dealing with this interrupt. **First Problem** I don't know whether Highest priority int reg = 0 is correct, maybe it should be 3FF after read IAR ?  **Second Problem** assume Core3 is dealing with SGI0, if I write 0 to EOI, the RPR value should be FF, but it keep 0...

Comment: Hi, Arun, a method can generate this BUG: **Core3 send SGI3 to itself**

Comment: and after avoid this, machine runs well now, but I can't sure whether this BUG has been resolved and don't know why.

Comment: The Question is: **ack SGI through EOI with the unmatched Core ID will cause this problem.**